# DataContext and Command in silverlight when used together is not working

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am using Silverlight 4.0 to implement MVVM architecture,
I have got a usercontrol TestMVVM.View.EmployeeView and a view EmployeeList within this usercontrol.
EmployeeList contains some textbox and a button.
My problem is when I use DataContext on the EmployeeList as given in the code  the command on button stops working but if I remove DataContext from EmployeeList the command of button works fine.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestMVVM.View.EmployeeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:TestMVVM.ViewModel"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:TestMVVM.View"          
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" 
    >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <VM:EmployeeListViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="160"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList,Mode=OneTime}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee,Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age,Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" />
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
        <view:EmployeeList  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedEmployee}" >

        </view:EmployeeList>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
//view 2
<UserControl x:Class="TestMVVM.View.EmployeeList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:TestMVVM.ViewModel" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" ></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="name" Text="Name" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txt_name" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" >
        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="age" Text="Age" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txt_age" Text="{Binding Age,Mode=TwoWay}" >
        </TextBox>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Add" Grid.Row="3" Content="Add" Command="{Binding Path=testCommand}" ></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically set the data context on your control, that control will create a new instance of that class. Hence, your EmployeeList and EmployeeView will be using different data context.

When you do not specifiy the data context on the EmployeeList user control, that control is inheriting the DataContext of its parent (ie, EmployeeGrid).  Typically, you WANT the control to inherit the data context of its parent so this is probably the configuration you are wanting.

It wasnt clear from your question what you were wanting... hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is not of DataContext but the Command="{Binding Path=testCommand}" which is on the button.When I click on the button the handler which I had created with the name testCommand is not handled and the function behind the testCommand is not executed.How can I allow testCommand to work when DataContext is set on the control.

Comment: What DataContext are you wanting on the control? Do you want it to have its own view model or use EmployeeListViewModel?

Comment: Basically EmployeeView contains a grid which is bound to EmployeeListViewModel and on the selection of any row of the grid I have set SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee,Mode=TwoWay} where SelectedEmployee is a property in EmployeeListViewModel and will contain data of single employee.This SelectedEmployee is passed to the view EmployeeList due to which data is displayed on the textbox of EmployeeList view.Now this EmployeeList view contains a button called Add which have the Command="{Binding Path=testCommand}",which fails to work.How can I write so that this button will fire the handler.

Comment: Do you need to set the DataContext on the control? Typically, you would not do this and let the DataContext of the control be inherited from its parent. If you do not set the DataContext on the control explicitly, then the control (in your case) will inherit its parent DataContext which is EmployeeListViewModel (which is what you want right?). Then you simply just do Command={Binding testCommand} and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the solution of my problem.What I have to do is to create two viewmodel one for EmployeeList and the second for EmployeeView and then the command of EmployeeView will start executing.