# Change binding source back to view model inside container in XAML

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I am using **Silverlight 4** and the **MVVM** pattern.

My view model has two properties:

- `SomeProperty` and
- `MyCommand`

`SomeProperty` is a complex type and has a lot of subproperties. `MyCommand` is a property to handle commanding from a Button.

I have a child window (the view) with a Grid as the `LayoutRoot` which is bound to the `SomeProperty` property of the view model.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
    ...
</Grid>
```

However, inside the Grid I want to bind a Button's `Command` property to the `MyCommand` property of the view model:

```
<Button Command={Binding MyCommand} />
```

But this is not working because `MyCommand` is a property of the view model, and not a property of the view model's `SomeProperty` property. (When I click on the Button it does not execute the command.)

Anywho, is there a way using data binding in Silverlight 4 such that I can have a container UI element set its `DataContext` property explicitly, but then have a different control within the container reference a property that's a sibling (or parent or whatever) of the `DataContext` of the containing control?

My current workaround is to define the binding in the view's class, but I'd rather have it in the XAML.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give your root element (ChildWindow, UserControl, whatever) a name, then you can use ElementName to get to the view model.

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyUserControl">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=MyUserControl}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Or, here's another way to do the same thing.

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyUserControl">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, ElementName=MyUserControl}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'd do, simple, easy to understand and just a little XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You try add datacontext to binding? The datacontext have to point to your viewmodel, because the default data context is a parent control or parent data context, in this case your layout root.

See [this](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/binding/data-binding-to-controls-%28silverlight-quickstart%29)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340434/datacontext-and-command-in-silverlight-when-used-together-is-not-working)

I hope this help.
Regards.

Comment: Yes, in my view's constructor I assign my view model to the view's `DataContext` property. The problem is that the LayoutRoot specifies ITS DataContext as a subproperty of the view model DataContext, and in the Button WITHIN the LayoutRoot I want to reference a property in the DataContext. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I use a version of the BindableProxy described in this post:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx

Above your Grid (probably within the UserControl.Resources) you would create:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ns:BindableProxy x:Key="BindableProxy" />
<UserControl.Resources>
```

Then, in the button binding:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataSource.MyCommand, Source={StaticResource BindableProxy}}" />
```